# Camera.open() gets "Access for <package> has been restricted"

Tags: android, android-camera, android-7.1-nougat

- Problem happening on a Nokia 6 with Android 7.1.1
- Permission granted
- `AppOpsManager#checkOp(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_CAMERA, Process.myUid(), getPackageName())` returns `AppOpsManager#MODE_ALLOWED`

Yet when trying Camera.open(i) for checking camera properties I get

> I/CameraService: Camera 0: Access for "package" has been restricted

Apparently this could only happen [1] if application's package or uId has been explicitly restricted from starting AppOpsManager#OP_CAMERA.
But why would this happen? After `AppOpsManager#checkOp` says `AppOpsManager#MODE_ALLOWED`

Sample code

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCameras; ++i) {
    List<Size> supportedSizes = null;
    List<int[]> supportedFpsRanges = null;
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(i);
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        supportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        supportedFpsRanges = getFpsRangesRobust(parameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }
```

[1] https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/oreo-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/AppOpsService.java#L2588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently it's a device issue.
Nokia 6 / TA-1000, Android 7.1.1

The scenario

- try to use camera
- app asks for permission, tap Deny
- try to use camera
- app asks for permission, tap Allow
- Error posted in logcat, camera doesn't work

Is reproducible with any other application, including the default camera app.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have added this line to your app manifest.

```
android:foregroundServiceType="camera"
```